# How to get the maximum element from a list

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a list of double

```
list<double> = ls{};
```

I insert some doubles to this list in a function I have.

I have to find the max, min, and avg element in the list. I tried for min and max the following, but I got errors error: (`cannot convert ‘std::_List_iterator<double>’ to ‘double’ in assignment`):

```
max_latecny = max_element(ls,ls+ls.size());
min_latency = min_element(ls,ls+ls.size());
```

Comment: Did you look up what the functions you're using actually do? What does `max_element()` return?

Comment: @Barry- Oh it returns an iteraor:/ Ok but I also get  the following error: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::list<double>’ and ‘std::list<double>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)|. So should I changed it to min_latency = min_element(arr.begin(),arr.end());

Comment: Is the list sorted? There are easy and simple methods if the list is sorted.

Comment: Please correct your question : `list<double> = ls{};` has a typo error. You init a list named `ls`, but later you talk about the `arr` variable. Please also give the prototype of `min_element()` or `max_element()`.

Comment: What is a "mid" element? Median? Average? The one in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v{9.2, 0.4, 2.5, 6.5, 4.3, 3.1, 9.7, 0.9, 1.2, 2.2, 1.09, 1.3};
    if (v.size()) {
      if (v.size() % 2) {
        std::cout << "Middle: " << v[v.size()/2] << "\n";
      } else {
        std::cout << "Middle: " << v[v.size()/2 - 1] << "\n";
      }
      std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
      if (v.size() % 2) {
        std::cout << "Median " << v[v.size()/2] << '\n';
      } else {
        auto second = v[v.size()/2];
        std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2 - 1, v.end());
        auto first = v[v.size()/2 - 1];
        std::cout << "Median " << " " << (first + second)/2 << '\n';
      }
      auto result = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
      std::cout << "Min: " << *result.first << "\nMax: " << *result.second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is **not** the median if the length of the range is even.

Comment: Updated, try this.